# Encoding issue. Convert to lisible string

Tags: ios, swift, string, encoding, text-decoding

I have a little issue in my project.

I fetch a JSON with strings like this "Paris 11'e8me", I want this to be displayed as "Paris 11ème".

My guess is that the string is encoded in sthg like isoLatin1. I want it to be displayed properly (utf8?)

How do I convert it ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
let encoedString = String(utf8String: stringToDecode.cString(using: .utf8)!)
```

Comment: I already tried this. And the string is still "Paris 11'e8me" any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

On decoding data use

```
String(data:dataString, encoding: .isoLatin1)
```

dataString is Data type